# How can I make one language to other language font converter Using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a converter using javascript which will convert one font to other. 
Example: If I type "A" to a form then the other font will display "আ".

Comment: do you want to change how the character looks? or change the character itself?

Comment: Presumably something like this: http://www.fliptext.org/

Comment: Yes I want a font converter just like this.

Comment: The question as asked is neither about languages nor about fonts. It is about characters. If you want to do character mappings, you first need to define the mapping, then decide whether how the mapping should be done (immediately as typed? or as batch when a button is clicked?), and then try it yourself, and post both your specifications and your best effort.

Answer (score 2):

After you've sent the form, just change the Fon't on the element you're displaying it in using  `@font-face`

Try something like this :

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa Regular';
    src: url('Comfortaa.eot');
    src: local('Comfortaa Regular'), 
         local('Comfortaa'), 
         url('Comfortaa.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Comfortaa.svg#font') format('svg'); 
}
```

And create a switch case that will choose what font-family to set on the element.

Comment: please tell of whole page code. I mean introducting  html code

Comment: You mean you want a copy-paste code without solving this on your own? or just to explain what you need to di in the HTML?

Comment: I know html code but i have just started to learn javascript. So i don't understand that where will use this code in body or head and how can i make form for this.

Answer (score 2):

Can you discuss more about your question? Are you talking about one area where text is entered, and another area where text is shown?